# Start Activity from Service and return to original application when it's finished?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an Android service that creates an global overlay in the bottom right of the screen for a user. This overlay displays over other applications.

When they tap it I want to open a one off settings page Activity from my app.

Once they hit save/cancel I want that Activity to close and take them back to whatever app they were in originally.

How can I accomplish this? Everything I seem to do returns to my MainActivity when the one off page is ended.

Service Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OneOffActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity Code

```
public class OneOffActivityextends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(this, "HIT THE ACTIVITY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    finish();
}
```

I've seen this done in a few other apps and am not sure how to replicate it.

Comment: Did you just try to finish your activity? Did it work?

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee Yes. It simply returns to the MainActivity at the root of my applicatiojn regardless of where the service was when starting the call.